# Protecting gmail security on work laptop

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

I worked on an office laptop and signed into my Gmail on Edge. I never logged out, and Edge automatically signs in if someone types in Gmail. What can do to prevent someone from logging into my Gmail and seeing my emails from my account if I no longer have access to the work laptop?